# Java stream generate and limit significance

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

For the following pieces of code:

**Block 1:**

```
Stream.generate(() -> "abcd")
.filter(n -> n.length() == 4)
.limit(2)
.sorted()
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Block 2:**

```
Stream.generate(() -> "abc")
.filter(n -> n.length() == 4)
.limit(2)
.sorted()
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I am trying to understand streams.

How does stream work internally? Does it always `filter` after producing one element ? Does `limit` also get fired after each element is generated ?

Comment: Java streams are *lazy*.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps

Comment: you do realize that the second one will never finish right?

Comment: @Eugene just the second snippet.

Comment: @Aominè ah! my bad